# Creating regression models

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I have a data.frame representing cars' braking distance and speed from which they were braking. The task I have says specifically that I have to create regression MODELS for it. What's more, my professor told me that I have to use entire set of data for the model. My question is, wouldn't every single model be exactly the same if I used the entire data set for it?

```
cars<- data.frame(speed, dist)
Model1 <- lm(dist~ speed, data=cars)
```

If I do `Model2` and `Model3` in the same way, the `summary(ModelX)` looks the same for each model. Am I doing something wrong, did I misunderstood something, or is there a way to create 3 different regression models using the same data?

Comment: Hint: Suppose you have $(x,y)$ data.  If you were to regress $y$ against $x$ using ordinary least squares, I suppose you would call that a "regression model."  But what if you were to regress $y$ and $x$ with different weights for each observation?  Or if you were to regress $y$ against $x$ and $x^2$?  Or if you were to use quantile regression to model $y$ in terms of $x$?  Would you think of any of these as a "regression model"?  Would they all have to be "exactly the same"?

Comment: This particular data set has been used in examples quite a few times on site (I've used it many times myself), and if you look around you should be able to locate a number of distinct models (not just the standard two-parameter OLS straight line model).  What sort of model for the mean might physics suggest? (at the least, what distance should you expect at speed 0?) Would the spread around the mean be constant or would it increase with speed? Would the distribution around the mean distance be symmetric or asymmetric (and if so, in which way)? These ideas may suggest modifications of the model